# Which event on a Control level is equivalent to Form.Load event?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, custom-controls

I am trying to create multiple custom controls in my application, For example:

```
Public Class CbsDataGridView
    Inherits DataGridView

    '...

    Private Sub CbsDataGridView_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Enter
        'Code here omitted, not related to the question.
        LoadGrid()
    End Sub

    Private Sub LoadGrid()
        'Code here omitted, not related to the question.
    End Sub

    '...

End Class

Public Class CbsDateTimePicker
    Inherits DateTimePicker

    Private Sub CbsDateTimePicker_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Enter
        'Code here omitted, not related to the question.
    End Sub

End Class
```

When adding these controls to a new empty form. Here's the two scenarios I've faced:

Scenario 1:

```
- Drag And Drop CbsDateTimePicker into the form
- Drag And Drop CbsDataGridView into the form
- Run Application - Load The New Form
- CbsDateTimePicker_Enter event fires.
- CbsDataGridView_Enter event doesn't fire.
```

Scenario 2:

```
- Drag And Drop CbsDataGridView into the form
- Drag And Drop CbsDateTimePicker into the form
- Run Application - Load The New Form
- CbsDataGridView_Enter event fires.
- CbsDateTimePicker_Enter event doesn't fire.
```

I think I miss-understood the `Enter` event of Controls.

What I am looking for is an event that acts like the `Form.Load` event which will fire when the form containing the control loads.

Is there a direct way to implement this functionality? Or should I be looking for another way?

Comment: [Enter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enter(v=vs.110).aspx) event will fire whenever the control gets focus using mouse or keyboard. Also whenever you set the active control of the form by code, the event will fire.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Which explains the undesired behavior I got. Whatever control I was adding first, was getting focused hence `Enter` event firing. Right?

Comment: They get focus at form load, based on the `TabIndex`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Enter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enter(v=vs.110).aspx) event will fire whenever the control activates by using mouse or keyboard. Also whenever you set the active control of the form by code, the event will fire.

Controls don't have a `Load` event similar to `Load` event of the `Form`, but they have a virtual [`OnCreateControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.oncreatecontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) which is called when the control is first created. You can override it and add custom logic to that method, or even raise a custom `Load` event for your control.

Comment: It seems calling `LoadData` is responsibility of the owner of those controls. The owner knows better when is suitable time to load data. So in general I prefer to make `LoadData` public and call it explicitly by the form which owns the control.

Comment: `OnCreateControl` worked well. We're trying to minimize the things that a developer has to remember when using such controls. Unless the `OnCreateControl` did any problem, I will switch to a `LoadData` public method and call it. Or just switch to a `UserControl` all together.

Comment: `Load` event of `UserControl` is also implemented using `OnCreateControl`.